# iis rewrite url for https://example.com/default.aspx/default.aspx to https://example.com

Tags: iis, web-config

I have tried all kinds of rewrite URL's and can't get IIS to send the URL of https://example.com/default.aspx/default.aspx to https://example.com/default.aspx

Google has indexed the site with the wrong URL when Bing got it right (go figure). Any help would be much appreciated. All my traffic is going to the wrong url (https://example.com/default.aspx/default.aspx).

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect www.xxx.com to xxx.com" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^https://example.com/default.aspx/default.aspx" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="default.aspx" />
    </rule>

    <rule name="redirect two character to default" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/[a-z]{2}(/)?$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="default.aspx" appendQueryString="false" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules Use FRT to learn what's wrong. One hint is that make sure every rule has exit conditions if necessary, so that it won't be executed over and over again. You should also learn from common mistakes, https://blog.lextudio.com/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59

Comment: the blog didn't help, common mistakes don't help, need solution. don't have access to iis on the server so setting up FRT is not possible.

Comment: Before running rules on a server that you have no access to, install IIS locally and test those rules from there.

Comment: don't know the rules, that is the problem. rules work for default.aspx but not for https://example.com/default.aspx/default.aspx. Every day I wait trying every possible solution is not helping, loosing business. Do you know the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some issue in your rule. {HTTP_HOST} only matches the hostname which is www.example.com it will not match the whole URL.

[image]

You could try below rule:

```
<rule name="Redirect www.xxx.com to xxx.com" enabled="true" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url=".*" />
  <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www.example.com" />
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="on" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="default/default|default.aspx/default.aspx" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="default.aspx" />
</rule>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jalpa! Thank-you!  Works like charm.